# How do I make a separate menu in my Visual Studio Integration Package (VSPackage)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vspackage

How do I make a separate menu in my Visual Studio Integration Package (VSPackage)? Every menu I create gets placed under "Tools" in VS2010. How do I get my own menu group in VS and then how do I add items underneath that menu group?

Comment: visual studio integration project = visual studio add-in project ?
Have you checked out this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb165473.aspx

Comment: no, they are different. Visual Studia integration package is VSPackage, VS add-in is the extensibility Microsoft is trying to make obsolete.

Comment: Please do not attempt this. Visual Studio already has up to 15+ top-level menus depending on context.

Comment: But how could I do it if I wanted to?

Comment: @280Z28 Maybe you should get a bigger monitor - I have room for at least another eight!

Comment: @dav_i I use a 30" (2560x1600) primary and 27" (2560x1440) secondary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [Link](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/04/17/LearnVSXNowPart18A.aspx) to create a Top level menu in Visual studio.